# How to write C# code to open an excel file and execute button click event?

Tags: c#, excel, com, interop

I need to write a C#.Net program to read an excel file for the below purposes

1. read excel content and update cell values
2. Execute a button click event which is in Excel

Please suggest with a sample codes

Comment: So, when you tried to do this, what happened?

Answer (score 2):

The [How to automate Microsoft Excel from Microsoft Visual C#.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/troubleshoot/office-developer/automate-excel-from-visual-c) article describes all steps for automating Excel from C#. The [Workbooks.Open](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Workbooks.Open) method opens a workbook. The file name of the workbook to be opened should be passed as a parameter.

```
      Excel.Workbooks objBooks;
      Excel.Sheets objSheets;
      Excel._Worksheet objSheet;

         // Instantiate Excel and start a new workbook.
         objApp = new Excel.Application();
         objBooks = objApp.Workbooks;
         objBook = objBooks.Open( filepath );
         objSheets = objBook.Worksheets;
         objSheet = (Excel._Worksheet)objSheets.get_Item(1);
```

You may also find the [How to automate Excel by using Visual C# to fill or to obtain data in a range by using arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/troubleshoot/office-developer/automate-excel-using-visual-c-fill-data) article helpful.

Please remember that Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution. Read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office) article.

You may consider using Open XML SDK instead, see [Getting started with the Open XML SDK 2.5 for Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/getting-started).